# Problema de codigo PHP para insertar parametros a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema que no entiendo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php
include('../Conexion/conexion.php');
$nombre = $_POST['NombreProducto'];
$rubro = $_POST['nuevoRubro'];
$categoria = $_POST['nuevaCategoria1'];
$nuevaSubcategoria = $_POST['nuevaSubcategoria'];
$nuevoStockAlerta = $_POST['nuevoStockAlerta'];
$nuevoStockMin = $_POST['nuevoStockMin'];
$nuevoPrecioCompra = $_POST['nuevoPrecioCompra'];
$nuevoPrecioVenta = $_POST['nuevoPrecioVenta'];
$nuevaMedida = $_POST['nuevaMedida'];
$nuevoCodigo = $_POST['nuevoCodigo'];
$TipoImpuesto = $_POST['TipoImpuesto'];
$nuevaTablaLista = $_POST['nuevaTablaLista'];
$nuevoImpuesto = $_POST['nuevoImpuesto'];

// Ver el tema de guardar imagenes
// $nuevaImagen = $_POST['nuevaImagen'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO inventarioproducto(Nombre,Rubro,categoria,subcategoria,stockalerta,stockmin,preciocompra,precioventa,medida,codigo,
impuesto,tablalista,imagen) 
VALUES ( '$nombre','$rubro','$categoria','$nuevaSubcategoria','$nuevoStockAlerta','$nuevoStockMin',
'$nuevoPrecioCompra','$nuevoPrecioVenta','$nuevaMedida','$nuevoCodigo','$TipoImpuesto','$nuevaTablaLista','$nuevoImpuesto')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar);

if ($resultado) {
    echo "<script>alert('Registrado con éxito')</script>";
    header('Location:../Apartados/InventarioProducto/productos.php');
    die;
}
```

La verdad no se cual podria ser el problema, va bastantes warning, por favor ayuda si alguien sabe sobre el tema, de ante mano muchísimas gracias

Comment: Listo estimado.

Comment: ¿Que necesitas que suceda? Por que evidentemente no le estas enviados por `POST` nada a ese archivo.

Comment: Es un formulario que registra productos, en el cual es un modal con inputs que registran los productos pero me sale esos errores

Comment: lo que necesito que suceda es que cuando rellene los campos se guarde en la base de datos

Comment: Deberías contener todo el código dentro de un `if`, para que solo se ejecute cuando los datos se enviaron, por ejemplo, `if (isset($_POST['NombreProducto'])) { /* todo tu código que guarda en la DB */ }`

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Donde corresponda revisa los datos están siendo enviados al script `php` por método **`POST`** (de preferencia que esté explícitamente indicado); adicionalmente hay otras dos situaciones que debes revisar.
Sin orden de importancia alguno; estas situaciones son:

- Los parámetros son enviados y sus respectivos valores.
- Que el nombre corresponde; PHP es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas; por ello debes revisar si los estas refiriendo como llegan.

Con lo anterior considero debes solucionar la situación; cumpliéndose los criterios.